# Image of square map on reductive group

Tags: algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\ss{ss}$Let $G$ be a reductive group over a field $F$ of characteristic 0. (Here not necessarily $F=\overline{F}$.) Consider the square map
$$
G(F)\longrightarrow G(F), \quad g\mapsto g^2.
$$

I know this map is not surjective in general even when $F=\overline{F}$. But how big is the image? Is the image Zariski open?

Also what if one restricts to semisimple elements? Namely, let $G(F)^{\ss}$ be the set of semisimple elements. Is the map
$$
G(F)^{\ss}\longrightarrow G(F)^{\ss}, \quad g\mapsto g^2,
$$
surjective, say, when $F=\overline{F}$?

Comment: In Question 1, do you mean the square map *on $F$-points* $G(F)\to G(F)$?

Comment: In Question 1, if $F$ is a *local field* ($\Bbb R$, or $\Bbb C$, or a $p$-adic field), then the answer is Yes for any connected algebraic group $G$, not necessarily reductive or linear.

Comment: In Question 2 for a connected reductive group $G$ over an algebraically closed field $F$ of characteristic 0, the answer is Yes.

Comment: Thanks. For Question 1, I mean G(F). (I edited the question.) Also for Question 2, do you know any reference for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to both questions are Yes.

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic 0 and ${\overline F}$ be a fixed algebraic closure of $F$.
Let $G$ be a connected reductive $F$-group.
By abuse of notation we identify $G$ with the set of ${\overline F}$-points $G({\overline F})$.
Let $G_s$ denote the subset of semisimple elements in $G$.
For a natural number $n>1$ we consider the map
$$\varphi_n\colon G\to G,\quad g\mapsto g^n.$$

> **Proposition 1.**  $\varphi_n(G_s)=G_s$.

*Proof.*
Let $s\in G_s$. It is known that  $s\in T$ for some maximal torus $T\subseteq G$.
For an element $s\in T$, it is clear that there exists an element $s'\in T\subseteq G_s$
such that $(s')^n=s$, which proves the proposition.

> **Theorem 2.** The set  $\varphi_n(G(F))$ is Zariski-dense in $G$.

*Proof.* Let $U\subseteq G$ be a nonempty open subset.
Consider the open subset $U_n:=\varphi_n^{-1}(U)\subseteq G$.
We show that $U_n$ is nonempty.
Indeed, consider the subset of regular semisimple elements $G_r\subseteq G_s\subseteq G$.
It is known that $G_r$ is open and nonempty.
Thus $U\cap G_r$ is open and nonempty.
Since $U\cap G_r\subseteq G_s$, by Proposition 1 $\varphi_n^{-1}(U\cap G_r)$ is nonempty.
Thus $U_n=\varphi_n^{-1}(U)$ is indeed nonempty.

By Corollary 18.3 in Borel's book (2nd edition) the set $G(F)$ is Zariski-dense in $G$.
Thus there exists an $F$-point $g\in G(F)\cap U_n$. Then $g^n=\varphi_n(g)\in \varphi_n(G(F))\cap U$.
Thus $\varphi_n(G(F))$ is Zariski-dense in $G$, as required.